# How to embed a standard delete page into a custom console?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a custom console, with the essential registers and the user can delete an object through this page. When he click on Delete I want show him the standard delete page without the sidebar and header. I know that is possible with isdtp=vw parameter. The problem is: When I redirect to standard page, I get this error: 
  "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://transp.na12.visual.force.com   from frame with URL https://na12.salesforce.com/setup/own/deleteredirect.jsp?delID=a...&isdtp=vw. Domains, protocols and ports must match."

And thereafter the page didn't work anymore. What should I do to solve that?

Comment: Is this in the Service Cloud Console? If so, please add the [service-cloud-console](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/service-cloud-console) tag.

Comment: No, it's just a visualforce page, that is used as a console.

Comment: Can you add the Javascript that is doing the redirect to the question? I suspect it isn't redirecting the top level browser window. Visualforce pages are served from a separate domain to standard Salesforce pages.